# Perl fetchrow_array retruns an empty array

Tags: perl, dbi

Hey Im coding a perl script which needs to get data from a database. But when I get a return value its comes back in an array so i dereference it. Yet it still prints out nothing. I ran the command in sqlplus and it worked there without issue. Im not sure how to solve this

Code:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select XMLRECORD from F_COMPANY") or
            die "Couldnt prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr;

$sth->execute();

# loop through the returned data 
while( my ($row) = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
   print "@$row\n";
}
```

OUTPUT: Literally nothing

[have tried like this too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApiL4.png)

Comment: The use of `printf` is wrong

Answer (score 5):

ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have caught your error.

`fetchrow_array` does NOT return an array reference. It returns the values of the row as individual scalars.

You want

```perl
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref() ) {  # aka `->fetch`
   say "@$row";
}
```

or

```perl
while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
   say "@row";
}
```

---

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   "dbi:SQLite:dbname=:memory:",
   "", "",
   {
      AutoCommit => 1,
      RaiseError => 1,
      PrintError => 0,
      PrintWarn  => 1,
   }
);

$dbh->do( "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `Table` ( `a` INT, `b` INT )" );
$dbh->do( "INSERT INTO `Table` VALUES ( 123, 456 )" );

{
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `Table`" );
   $sth->execute();
   while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref() ) {  # aka `->fetch`
      say "@$row";
   }
}

{
   my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `Table`" );
   $sth->execute();
   while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
      say "@row";
   }
}
```

Output:

```
123 456
123 456
```

Comment: Hello thank you for a response, I have tried it the ways u said to and both of them send back addresses, like "ARRAY(0x...). And when i try to loop through each array it gives nothing. But in sqlplus it shows proper data.

Comment: I stand by what I said. 1) You're still not using `use strict;`, and 2) you didn't use one of these snippets.

Comment: Hey sorry I shouldve specified, I tried both methods and they give the same result. Use strict and warnings are declared at the very top of my script.

Comment: Then you literally have "ARRAY(0x...)" for data in the database.

Comment: hm thats weird, the db had something else. ill try playing around with it more

Comment: One of the snippets I posted throws an error when used, so you obviously didn't use it. (Fixed)

Comment: yes it cannot do undef i belive, I ignored that cause it wasn't the issue at hand. that SS is only one of them running. Do appreciate the help man

Comment: Re "*yes it cannot do undef i belive*", No, it handles undef fine. (Obviously, the stringification results in a warning, but the question isn't about that.)

Comment: I added proof to my answer

Comment: Hey man tried your edit and it works much better and more clear. It still printed out the Array addresses. And when i went into them it printed out nothing. You proved your code, so I think the problem lies within what the db is storing. Sorry if my knowledge is low, this is my first project as an intern haha. Thanks a bunch man.